# Unable to read Map<String,Object> field from couchbase using spring data couchbase

Tags: spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Facing issue while loading document with Map<String,Object> type in my model.

```
protected Map<String, Object> attributes;
```

while loading data from couchbase getting *Basic type must not be null!* error.

is there any way we can load such attributes from couchbase, I am able to store but loading has issue.

Answer (score 0):

> protected Map<String, Object> attributes;

It's not possible to construct objects of type Object from data from a document. The second parameter of Map must be an entity or simple type.